# How to delete everything an 'eval' created

Tags: javascript, html, function, eval

I have this code where I create an interval using an eval (the code below is just a dummy code) but everytime I run `createInterval()` it doesn't override the first one so now I have two or more intervals. Now how would I remove everything an eval created so that I only have the newest one?

You can see in the snippet that multiple intervals are running if you click the button multiple times.

Edit: I tried clearing it using clearInterval but still didnt work

```js
function createInterval() {
  if(typeof clock !== "undefined") clearInterval(clock);
  eval("var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); var clock = setInterval(() => {console.log(num)}, 1000 + num)");
}
createInterval();
```

```html
<button onclick=createInterval() style="padding: 20px"></button>
```

Comment: "Now how would I remove everything an eval created so that I only have the newest one?" - do you mean you want to cancel all active and pending `setInterval` callbacks?

Comment: Why would you use `eval`?

Comment: @Dai yeah, also everything else that it makes like variables, functions etc. I just didn't add them

Comment: @KonradLinkowski well I'm trying to create a javascript code tester where users (or just me) can input code and it will run on the page

Comment: You wan to create something like jsfiddle, codepen or the snipped editor here on SO? They all use an iframe to load the code in an isolated document that document can be replaced in the case when  everything should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `clearInterval(clock)`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: I tried it, didn't work.

Comment: I think that you lose the reference to clock with the eval.

Comment: @noon Please edit your post to show us your code where you use `clearInterval`.

Comment: @Dai I did add it